# ARP behind router with NAT?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, nat, arp

```
        Router                     Access Point
```

192.168.0.10  |  192.168.5.1................192.168.5.7<--NAT<--192.168.10.1

In this topology, the clients in the AP get translated to the internet interface which is X.X.5.7. I want the router to perform authentication actually per individual client in the AP but because it sees only the IP of the X.X.5.7 and it's gateway and authenticates that , all users in the AP are automatically authenticated. What i want to do is for the router to be able to authenticate each client with their MAC address instead of the AP internet gateway. But since they are behind NAT, i can't see a way to do it. Any ideas how ARP could successfully resolve the MACs when the clients are being translated ? If there isn't any working solution(like changing the protocol/header), maybe your ideas of how to make it possible logically will be helpful. NAT has to stay. i could easily resolve it without NAT. But in my network NAT is of essence ! :)

Comment: what kind of router and AP are you using?

Comment: @MikePennington I am using a Linksys DDWRT for AP. And an embedded computer linux distribution as router running ZEROSHELL.

Answer (score 0):

The X.X.5.7 and X.X.10.1 are **likely** in different subnets, so you would not be able to get ARP messages from one subnet to another. ARP is sent only in the same subnet. If the destination is in a different subnet, then the host (sitting behind the AP) would simply send it to the gateway (perhaps the AP).

You mentioned that you were able to do this without NAT. I am curious without NAT, did you put the clients in the X.X.10.1 subnet or in X.X.5.1 subnet?